# Javascript default text in textfield like tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, validation

I want a default text in the input filed with grey color. But a user should not be able to select this text and also it is non deletable.

Example:

User types the name `Susan`. After they stop typing it would appear like this: `SusanCartel`.   The grey part shows up automatically as a preview. Then when they hit create we would see `SusanCartel`. This way, people wont type in `SusanCartelCartel` by accident because they will see the preview.

Comment: Sounds like you want more something like Google Instant uses, showing the autocomplete result *inside* the textbox. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336094/jquery-autocomplete-in-background-of-input-text-box and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376956/make-part-of-inputtext-grey

Comment: @close voter - that question is not even close to being a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Rory: Got the wrong link, the others probably fit though...

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 has the new `placeholder` attribute you can use:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Type your username..." />
```

However this will not work in IE, or older browsers.

[This plugin](http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/) will achieve the same effect cross-browser.

Comment: It seems to me OP wants to some autocomplete information to the input box, like Google Instant, not some static text. The question is a bit vague though.

Comment: actually I want something like if a user click into the textbox then a word "cartel" should appear automatically into the textbox just after the what we are typing. The word "Cartel" should not be selectable and editable or deletable.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use jquery-watermark. Check out this [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)  link for more info.

Usage :

```
$('#inputid').watermark('Required information', {className: 'myClassName'});
```

Also if you read the introduction carefully, you'll come across this point

> Supports HTML5 "placeholder" capabilities natively (in browsers that
>   support it), or native support can be disabled so that the plugin
>   controls all watermarks

Comment: why not just use the native html5 placeholder?

Comment: You can, but this takes care of those browsers that CANT support HTML5